# Razor view is only updated after build

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I made some changes to a Razor view in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project, but they did not appear on my screen. Not after a couple of CTRL+F5's in the browser.
I had to build the project to get the changes in my browser.

Of course, I looked in my csproj file, but it has the `<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>` setting to false.

Is there anywhere else I should look? Is there any other setting that could be caching or pre-compiling views?

Comment: Your browser can cache the pages.

Comment: I'd think that a couple of times hitting CTRL+F5 in the browser would get me the page from the server instead of the local browser cache

Comment: Did you *Save* the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for some reason, in Visual Studio, you may see this problem (bug)!  In order to solve this problem, you should right-click on your solution (in Solution Explorer) and then click on the "Clean Solution" option.